# How can I get the most recent file from a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

```
cached_folder = os.path.expandvars(r'%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\*')
list_of_files = glob.glob(cached_folder)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

I just want the path of the most recent file in CachedFiles although this doesn't work and `list_of_files` is an empty list.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you verify that `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles` is not actually empty? The code you posted worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below (essentially wrapping your code) worked for me.
You may have an empty
`%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def main():
    import os, glob
    cached_folder = os.path.expandvars(r'%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\*')
    list_of_files = glob.glob(cached_folder)
    print( list_of_files )
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    print( latest_file )
    return

if (__name__ == '__main__' ) :
    main()
```